# Dollar sign replacement not working Java

Tags: java, regex

Okay so I've been reading posts(alot) about the `$` sign in java and regex and stuff. But for some reason, each time I try to replace it, it gives me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I'm trying to parse a string begining with a `$` sign into an integer.

When I do `$test` it gives me a `NumberFormatException` (which is what I want) but when I do `$5` it gives me the other Exception (`IndexOutOfBoundsException`) although i'm changing it to `\0024` and adding in the number following it... Anyone mind helping me? Thanks!

```
if (w.charAt(0) == '$') {
    try {
        w = w.replace("\u0024", "");
        int i = Integer.parseInt(w);
        m.appendReplacement(sb, ChatTweaks.Citrus.get("dollarIn") + "" + '\u0024' + i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nume) {
        ChatTweaks.showMsg(ChatTweaks.prefix + "Please use numbers after your dollar signs ($)w=" + w);
        return;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ChatTweaks.showMsg(ChatTweaks.prefix + "Unknown exception ex: " + ex + " w:" + w);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u0024` is the Unicode escape sequence for the dollar sign. Your code is checking for the dollar sign (`w.charAt(0) == '$'`), removing it (`w = w.replace("\u0024", "")`), then putting it back again (`'\u0024' + i`).

**Edit:** I knew this was strange, but I missed the actual problem. I see now; Matcher.appendReplacement is complaining because there is a $+number sequence in the replacement, and is treating it as a reference to a captured group.

This is because `\u0024` does *not* escape anything as far as appendReplacement is concerned, because that escape sequence is parsed at compile time. By run time, a string written in the source as `"\u0024"` has length **1**, and its only character is a literal dollar sign. (In fact, Unicode escape sequences are almost the first thing parsed by the Java compiler, right after counting lines. For example, you can declare a variable `int $foo;` and then use it in code (outside of regexes or even strings) with `\u0024foo = 123;` (or `\u0024\u0066\u006f\u006f = 123;`)).

To escape a dollar sign for appendReplacement, escape it with a backslash. Because escape sequences in strings are parsed at compile time, you must also escape the backslash. I.e.,

```
m.appendReplacement(sb, ChatTweaks.Citrus.get("dollarIn") + "\\$" + i);
```

To clarify, at compile time, the compiler sees `"\\$"` and creates a string of length 2; whose characters are \ and $. At run time, appendReplacement can see them and insert just a $.

The method [Matcher.quoteReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29) can also do this for you, which is a good idea in case `ChatTweaks.Citrus.get("dollarIn")` could also return any dollar signs that it's not supposed to and which would also upset the matcher. E.g.,

```
m.appendReplacement(sb,
    Matcher.quoteReplacement(ChatTweaks.Citrus.get("dollarIn") + "$" + i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your replacement code works fine for me, but...
why use the regex to remove the first character? This is more straightforward, and works just as well:

```
w = w.substring(w.length()-1)
```

Also, for code readability, '$' and "$" are just fine - since '$' is a single-byte character, it should be equivalent to '\u002' - or do you have some special requirement?

See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html for a semi-humorous outlook on why regex probably shouldn't be the first thing that comes to mind when you're trying to solve a text-manipulation problem.

Comment: The thing is, its thinking im using regex when I use the $ sign.... so idk how to cancel that out D:

Comment: if by 'it', you mean the String.replace(String, String) method, it only works with regex. So you'd have to escape the dollar-sign to make it a literal, by preceding it with a back-slash, as in              `w.replace("\$", "")` but I would still recommend the substring method  instead.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek: "if by 'it', you mean the String.replace(String, String) method, it only works with regex". This is not correct. `String.replaceAll` and `String.replaceFirst` are regex methods. `String.replace` does a plain, literal find and replace. @Zacky1 You don't need to cancel anything out. As I've pointed out in my answer, your code works perfectly in that it successfully removes the dollar sign; it's just that for no reason, you put the dollar sign back again 2 lines later.

Comment: Ya, but I want to show the dollar sign... If there's an easier way to make sure the numbers after the dollar signs are integers, throw it out to me haha... I just don't understand why it's always looking for a group even though I use the escape sequence (or use it as a string)...

and btw, its saying the error is @ `m.appendReplacement(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing and parsing as you coded, is working for me. `String.replace(String,String)` will not consider the argument as a regex. If you want to pass a regex as argument, use `String.replaceAll(String,String)` or `String.replaceFirst(String,String)`.

`String.replaceAll` replaces all patterns matching the regex given as first argument with the string given as second argument.

`String.replaceFirst` replaces first pattern matching the regex given as first argument.

So use `w.replace("$", "")` if you want to replace every `$` sign in `w`. Here, `"$"` is not treated as a regex.

Or use `w.replaceAll("\\$","")`. Here `"\\$"` is treated as regex.

Or use `w.replaceFirst("\\$","")` if you want to replace only the first `$` in the string.